# I am broadcasting every table join, but still get SortMergeJoin calls and 2 tasks that never complete

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running on a 50 node AWS EMR cluster r5.24xlarge
96 vCore, 768 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:1000 GiB
Spark 3.2.1

Stage 20 is failing and it appears to be from disk spillage where I am getting
log messages like

```
INFO UnsafeExternalSorter: Thread 163 spilling sort data of 20.4 GiB to disk (107  times so far)
```

I've logged into the failing node and indeed I do see a disk utilization error over 90%.

There seems to be two tasks that are taking all the time in this stage based on the graph
[exectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMj6D.png)

From my understanding this indicates a major data skew, but I am having a hard time identifying where and why this is happening. I have a main table which is 15 million rows and gets exploded to 70 times that in the code. I join in with several other smaller tables. I tried broadcasting all of the table joins but I still see this skew. My understanding is that I should not be seeing a SortMergeJoin since all joins should be broadcast as seen in Stage DAG[Stage DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqLII.png)

The code is very complex so I can't really enter it here. Is there any other transformations I should look for that could cause this kind of skew? My run config is:

```
spark_conf.set("spark.executor.cores", 5)
spark_conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "35g")
spark_conf.set("spark.executor.instances", 479)
spark_conf.set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "5g")
spark_conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "35g")
spark_conf.set("spark.network.timeout", 1000)
spark_conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "500m")
spark_conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", 21000)
spark_conf.set("spark.memory.storageFraction", 0.2)
spark_conf.set("spark.driver.cores", 5)
spark_conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 21000)
spark_conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false")
spark_conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true")
spark_conf.set("spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.cleanCheckpoints", "true")
spark_conf.set("spark.checkpoint.compress", "true")
spark_conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.maxRecordsPerBatch", -1)
```

Could this be something other than skew?

This seems to be the code responsible for my issue. Before the join the data is partitioned, but after the join all the data is pulled into one parition

```
asm = self.spark_session.createDataFrame(asm_pd, schema=asm_schema).drop("2009")
        asm_b = f.broadcast(asm)
        df.groupBy(f.spark_partition_id()).count().show(200) 
        print("before asm join")
        # assumption name is under index
        df = df.join(asm_b, df["join_asm"] == asm_b["index"]).drop("join_asm", "index")
        df.groupBy(f.spark_partition_id()).count().show(200) 
        print("after asm join")
```

Comment: Your code might be complex but when trying to solve such a problem, it could be very interesting to try and implement a minimal example that reproduces it. It could help you you pinpoint the source of the issue yourself. It would also allow us to help you. Without the code it is hard to see for instance why the table of the join does get broadcasted.

Comment: I've actually found the snippet of code causing the issue but I am at my wits end and cannot figure out why this code is causing all the data to be pulled into one partition. I've added the code here.